# Trying to create composite primary key using Hibernate annotations for a One-To-Many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

I'm trying to model a unidirectional OneToMany relationship using Hibernate3 with annotations. The scenario is that a user *has* many articles and an article *has* many users. In the workflow a user can read one of these articles in which case I would like to move it to a persisted list of "read" articles. This is where the one-to-many relationship occurs as far as the Java model is concerned. A user *has* a list of "read" articles that belong to that individual user.

The issue is that the table can have many users with many articles, so the primary key should be a composite of both the user_id and the article_id. However, with my current setup the article_id is being set as the primary key. This is creating a bug where I can insert a "read" article into the table just fine the first time it's ready, but as soon as a second user tries to read the article it throws a duplicate key exception.

Here is my Java set up:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinTable(name = "educational_article_read", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")})
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private List<EducationalArticleModel> articles_read = new ArrayList<EducationalArticleModel>();
```

Here is the resulting table schema:

```
mysql> describe educational_article_read;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| article_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

The error stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '55' for key 'article_id'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '55' for key 'article_id'
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:138)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:594)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:476)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:387)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.bosch.dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f17df281.update(<generated>)
```